# How to let user enter a JavaScript function securely?

Tags: javascript, parsing, function, boolean, truthtable

What I'm doing is creating a truth table generator. Using a function provided by the user (e.g. `a && b || c`), I'm trying to make JavaScript display all combinations of a, b and c with the result of the function.

The point is that I'm not entirely sure how to parse the function provided by the user. The user could namely basically put everything he wants in a function, which could have the effect of my website being changed etc.

`eval()` is not secure at all; neither is `new Function()`, as both can make the user put everything to his liking in the function. Usually `JSON.parse()` is a great alternative to `eval()`, however functions don't exist in JSON.

So I was wondering how I can parse a custom boolean operator string like `a && b || c` to a function, whilst any malicious code strings are ignored. Only boolean operators (`&&, ||, !`) should be allowed inside the function.

Comment: and how do you define what constitutes "malicious code"?

Comment: Can't the user use the browser console and execute whatever JS he wants to anyway? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well - that's correct. However what I mean is that I would like to be able to see whether a function is a combination of boolean operators (`a && b || c`) or that it is something containing AJAX calls etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you check for boolean expressions, I could do this:

```
(a && b && (function() { ruinYourShit(); return true; })())
```

This is to illustrate that your problem is not solvable in the general case.

To make it work for your situation, you'd have to impose severe restrictions on variable naming, like requiring that all variables are a single alphabet letter, and then use a regular expression to kick it back if anything else is found. Also, to "match" a boolean expression, you'd actually have to develop a grammar for that expression. You are attempting to parse a non-regular language (javascript) and therefore you cannot write a regular expression that could match every possible boolean expression of arbitrary complexity. Basically, the problem you are trying to solve is really, really hard.

Assuming you aren't expecting the world to come crashing down if someone ruins your shit, you can develop a **good enough solution** by simply checking for the `function` keyword, and disallowing any logical code blocks contained in `{` and `}`.

Comment: Well, things like ignoring code with a `{` is a good start I guess. Thanks for your example.

Comment: @pimvdb: I can't tell from you question, but if your filtering is related to security, you definitely want to do *white* listing, as opposed to *black* listing!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem with using eval() and letting the user do whatever (s)he wants, as long as you have proper validation/filters on any of your server-side scripts that expect input.  Sure, the user could do something that ruins your page, but (s)he can do that already.  The user can easily enough run any javascript (s)he wants on your page already, using any number built-in browser features or add-ons.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do would be to first split the user input into tokens (variable names,  operators and possibly parentheses for grouping), then build an expression tree from that and then generate the relevant output from the expression tree (possibly after running some simplification on it).

So, say, break the string "a & !b" into the token sequence "a" "&" "!" "b", then go through and (eventually) build something like: booland(boolvar("a"), boolnot(boolvar("b"))) and you then have a suitable data structure to run your (custom, hopefully injection-free) evaluator over.

Comment: That seems to become rather complex, but it certainly is a good method.

Comment: Shouldn't need to be too complex, you can leverage regexps for your tokenisation and with a suitable tokeniser class to keep state (essentially "where are we now, in the string"), it should be possible to do close to a single pass across your string for tokenising, then using Dijkstra's Shunting Yard algorithm to build the expression tree. Having hand-coded similar things for more "full" mathematical expressions a few times, it should not take more than a few hours. Alternatively, look for a parser generator for JavaScript (I do not know if such a beast exists).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a regular expression:

```
if(!/^[a-zA-Z\|\&\!\(\)\ ]+$/.test(str)) {
   throw "The function is not a combination of Boolean operators.";
   return;
}
```